# Accessible only by logged in users pages

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to make my admin.php page only accessible to a logged in person so when your not logged in you will be sended to index.php. I have tried something with a if statement but it does not seem to work for me?

**loginHTML.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="verification.php" class="loginFields">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inloggen">
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
// Start new DOMDocument and load html file.
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("loginHTML.html");
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

// Haal verification.php op om gegevens te checken.
include_once('verification.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $object = new user();
    $object->login($username, $password);
}
// Save DOMDocument with html document.
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**verification.php**

```
// Include connection.php om connectie te maken te de database.
include_once('inc/connection.php');
include_once('login.php');

class user{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbconnect();
    }


    public function login($username, $password){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();

        // Als $username en $password gevuld zijn checken op overeenkomst
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $username);
            $st->bindParam(2, $password);
            $st->execute();
            $result=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $id=$result['id'];

            // Als er een overeenkomst is doorsturen naar admin.php en session aanmaken
            if($st->rowCount() == 1) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
                $_SESSION['ingelogt'] = $username;
                header('location: admin.php');
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Incorrect username or password";
            }

        // Als er niks is ingevoerd bij het inlogscherm
        } else {
            echo "Please enter your username and password";
        }
    }
}
```

**admin.php**

```
session_start();
// If session is not ingelogt lead back to index.php.
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("location: index.php"); 
    die();
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I know that page and i have looked into it but i can't seem to find the right one.. some help please? @deceze

Comment: after `$st->execute();` -> `$result=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $id=$result['id']` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Also, please use 2 separate queries - select a username and get it's id. Then select for password for ID of the user.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the answer could u also answer my new question ? i have just changed the question on this topic since i can't make another one already.

Comment: ohh sorry, i did not see i unaccepted it! i have changed the data from this question since i cant ask another one yet. could u perhaps help me with this one also?

Comment: @MikePortanger what is your question now?

Comment: Its above i have changed the question its about a page that will only be accesible by a logged in person

Comment: @MikePortanger it should work, you get any error? make sure you dont have any html before this check and dont echo anything as well

Comment: @meda When i am logged in a get directed to index.php.. its so weird. dunno what im doing wrong.. im using the code i pasted above

Comment: @MikePortanger right before `$_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];` add `session_start();` one more time

Comment: @MikePortanger ok good luck bro

Comment: @MikePortanger Im not sure you're aware of this; but you may want to hash your password. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php also http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Hi, yes im aware of that i have to do that but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `SELECT *`, instead specify the columns `SELECT id`

```
//...
$st->execute();
$row = $st->fetch();

$id = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've successfully selected **All** from *users* using `*`. Now all you have to do is fetch.

> $users = $stmt->fetchObject();

Now just `echo` the following: `$users->data`

**Example:**

> echo $users->id;
>
> echo $users->username;

**OR**

If you simply want just the ID you should really be only selecting the ID like this: `SELECT id`, not all (`*`).